# How to display an UIView above NavigationController and UITabbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

I am trying to create a custom Actionsheet controller (as I want it to be similar to action sheet even on the iPad). I am using XIB's in my project to load views.

I have a `View Controller A` on which I want to show a custom Table view from bottom (Just to mimic the actionSheet behavior). But when I do so by adding it to custom View in my View Controller A, the view stays below the NavigationController and UITababar of the that View controller.

```
    let vc = CustomActionTableViewController(nibName: "CustomActionTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    self.actionView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    let horzConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[childView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["childView": vc.view])

    let vertConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[childView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["childView": vc.view])

    view.addConstraints(horzConstraints)
    view.addConstraints(vertConstraints)
    vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

[image: This is my implementation]

I want to add this to a view so that I can achieve transparent background even over Navigation controller and UITabbar.

[image: Something like this]

How can I achieve this. And further more how is it possible to create Card like bottom views used for AirPods connectivity ? Can this kind of view be mimicked using Apple's UIKit or any Library ?[image]

Comment: if you wanna go on top of every thing(tab bar nav bar etc.) you can create a new UIWindow put your UIViewController on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `present` this `ViewController` with `modalPresentationStyle` as `.overFullScreen`

```
let vc = CustomActionTableViewController(nibName: "CustomActionTableViewController", bundle: nil)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can set the background `color` of `CustomActionTableViewController`'s `view` as black and change `alpha` value to set the transparency.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great. And also could you tell me if we could somehow use the cards like that one in the last screen shot (AirPods connectivity). Can this be done ?

Comment: For this, create a separate `ViewController` e.g, `CardViewController` and create card `view` inside that and just `present` as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class SetupSheet: UIViewController {
    var content: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.6)
        
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        displaySetupSheet()
    }

    private func displaySetupSheet() {
        content.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: view.frame.maxY, width: view.bounds.width - 16 , height: view.bounds.height / 2)
        content.backgroundColor = .white
        content.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCurlUp) {
            self.content.frame.origin.y -= (self.view.bounds.height / 2) + 16
        }
    }
}
```

I know this post is a little older, but I tried quite a few things and this may help someone. Here's a finished reusable "Airpod" style setup sheet. It is a view controller so you can present it using `present()`. When you initialize, assign to content a UIView that contains whatever inner content you want to show. [Here's a pic used in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6oic.jpg)